# Qual a precisão da geolocalização do React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocalização

Qual a precisão dos dados da geolocalização do React Native. Ele usa a geolocalização nativa do celular?

Queria ter uma ideia da margem de erro da localização, se é em grandeza de metros ou quilômetros, ou se é bem precisa, na ordem de centímetros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, o React Native utiliza a geolocalização nativa do celular.

Apesar da API Geolocation ser exposta através de polyfills (**[navigator.geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation)**), o sinal de GPS utilizado é o mesmo do dispositivo.

Isso já responde a segunda pergunta (precisão): o GPS da maioria dos aparelhos de celular de hoje em dia retornam sua localização com uma margem de erro de apenas alguns metros. Tenha em mente que isso varia de acordo com o lugar que você está utilizando o GPS.

- Dentro de um edifício de concreto você provavelmente não vai obter uma localização confiável.
- Dentro de um carro, 10-50 metros de margem de erro;
- À pé: 5-10 metros de margem.